# highlight vertices in OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm learning about OpenGL on Android. I have problems understanding the 'drawing of faces'. The clockwise/counter clockwise logic is very confusing for me. I was wondering if there's an option to NOT create faces and simple highlight each point (vertex) in OpenGL? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glPolygonMode[[link]](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glPolygonMode.xml) is what you are looking for!

ex. glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_POINT) is what you requested.

Comment: `glPolygonMode()` is not supported in OpenGL ES, which is what the OP would be using on Android.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. @RetoKoradi's answer should be marked as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to your draw calls specifies what kind of primitive you want to draw. The most common are triangles, but you can also draw points. So if you currently have draw calls that look like this:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, ...);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ...);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, ...);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, ...);
```

you can simply change the first argument to draw points instead:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, ...);
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, ...);
```